# :inverse_of not working through accepts_nested_attributes_for relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, nested-attributes, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have something kind of like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos, inverse_of: :project
  has_many :bars, inverse_of: :project
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :foos
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bars

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project, inverse_of: :bars
  has_and_belongs_to_many :foos

  validates_presence_of :project
end

proj = Project.create
foo  = Foo.new(project: project, bars_attributes: {0 => [name: "first bar"]})
foo.save! #-> Bar is invalid
```

Foos and Bars both belong to a Project, and a habtm relationship joins them...

I want to be able to create new Foos for the Bar, and have them belong to the Bar's project... but the project validation is failing.

I'm doing this through ActiveAdmin, but I'm trying to solve it at the model/relationship level before getting hacky with InheritedResources overrides...

Comment: `accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar` should be `accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars`.May be this is causing the problem.

Comment: Ah thanks for catching that; fixed in the example.  But in my real app I have that correctly pluralized, so that's not it...